# SSH Putty newline ... bug?

Tags: ssh, putty

Sometimes when I'm messing around with putty and do a Ctrl+C on certain commands (or similar), the terminal get messed up.

By "messed up" I mean that when I press enter, the newline is not inserted and the entire layout get messed up. Also, when I write something it doesn't appear, only when I press enter.

Like that:

[image: Glitched SSH session]

Why this happens? What can I do to reverse this ... bug? I know that closing and reopening the console is a "solution", but sometimes that's annoying, there must be a way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

- `clear` (or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>) to clear the terminal window.
- `reset` to reset the terminal if it is messed up by control sequences.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> According to [this](https://superuser.com/a/640341/365077), `reset` might clear some key binds.

Comment: Somewhere between these two (I think) is another option, the one I use (mainly from force of habit): `stty sane`.